# htaccess 301 redirects - need help

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm stuck. I don't know much about htaccess and I'm just winging it. Can someone look at the code and tell me what's wrong with it. I simply want to redirect an old site to a new site and the only changes are the domain, a variable that will match between old/new pages and an added word to the permalink structure.

Here's one of the variations I've tried so far:

```
Options +FolowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain.com/matchingword1-(.*)-matchingword2-matchingword3/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/matchingword1-$1-matchingword2-differentword-matchingword3/ [R=301,L]
```

The section `(.*)` will be the exact same as $1 on the new domain but the permalink is a little different. The part of the permalink that is `(.*)` will be anything from multiple words and numbers.

For example: `matchingword1-this-page-is-1st-matchingword2-matchingword3/` redirects to `newdomain.com/matchingword1-this-page-is-1st-matchingword2-differentword-matchingword3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FolowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^.*domain.com/matchingword1-(.*)-matchingword2-matchingword3/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What is the point of having `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` here if you already matching URL in RewriteRule pattern ?

Comment: @LazyOne I think he wants to redirect only those URLs that match the format he gave!

Comment: Yes, correct. But why do you need that if you can match/do the same in RewriteRule pattern itself (1 line less, 1 less comparison = a bit faster execution)??